# Отображение огромного количества символов

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Пишу проект на `Vue.js` и возник вопрос отображения огромного количества текста. Как выяснилось даже пустой документ содержащий более миллиона символов начинает сильно тормозить при выделении либо редактировании его. Есть ли какие либо способы предотвратить это? Вариант при котором текст отображается частями к сожалению не подходит(

Comment: Почему не подходит вариант с отображением текста частями?
В чем необходимость отображать на странице такое большое количество текста?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, ну представьте что вам нужно отобразить книгу, при этом пользователь захочет выделить огромный кусок в книге. При разбивке это сильно усложнит процесс

Comment: Только частично отображать - другого способа нету.

Comment: Можно запретить стандартный способ выделения и копирования.
В замен ему написать свой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## как отображать книги на сайте ?

### вариант первый - книга имеет формат `.txt`

в этом случае обычно файл считывается и помещается

- в одну переменную
- в массив строк , которые, к стати говоря, уже проще отображать частями.
  разделение книги в этом случае происходит, например, по абзацам (`/\n\n/g`)

### частями или весь текст отображать

> Вариант при котором текст отображается частями к сожалению не подходит(

дайте пользователю возможность решить самому

#### преимущества отображения целиком

- не нужно писать поиск по книге (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> есть в каждом браузере)
- т.к. весь текст в одной переменной легче написать свой способ выделения (например с помощью перетаскивания флажков)

#### недостатки отображения целиком

- возможны тормоза при отображении целиком
- нет навигации
- нет картинок
- нет стилистического оформления
- ...

### вариант альтернативный - использовать книги в формате `.fb2`

fb2 "[FictionBook](http://www.fictionbook.org/index.php/FictionBook)" переводится как "Художественная книга".
fb2 - очень популярный, открытый формат хранения книг ([описание формата FB2 от Sclex](http://www.fictionbook.org/index.php/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_FB2_%D0%BE%D1%82_Sclex)). поддерживается большим количеством читалок, в том числе и электронных. есть читалки, написанные на JS, например:

- [плагин для firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fb2-reader/)
- [этот же плагин на github](https://github.com/tymofij/fb2reader)